# UBUNTU Windows Common Storage

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I bought myself a new laptop with 1 TB hard-disk.While installing Ubuntu i made that Windows 10 stays in a 200 GB partition.I thought i could create a partition  for Ubuntu while installing but i couldn't.So now i have 200 GB for Windows and 800GB for Ubuntu. I would like to leave 100 GB for Ubuntu and have 700 GB common storage to access from both storage.So any idea how i can do it?
I kinda new to Ubuntu and I would like to have your help?
Thanks!**

Comment: Give Windows the larger partition. When logged into Ubuntu you can mount the NTFS filesystem. The Windows partition (NTFS) could not see the Ubuntu system, but the Ubuntu system could see the Windows partition (NTFS). You may need to run gparted from a Ubuntu on USB to shrink the size of your Ubuntu partition. Then you should be able to adjust your Win 10 partition to the size you need.

Comment: You may use _gparted_ to shrink the Ubuntu partition then access the extra space accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to Ubuntu and install Gparted
you can find it in the software center or install it via terminal:

```
sudo apt install gparted
```

after installing you can run gparted and resize the partition of ubuntu to the size you want it to have. This should work without a problem on a fresh install since the overall partition usage should be way below 100GB.

After the Resizing of the Ubuntu Partition you should be able to use gparted or windows to create a NTFS partition that you can then use/mount in Ubuntu too.